# can we get the details of the class db.t2.large using AWSCLI commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, rds

can we get the details of the class (db.t2.large) like CPU is 2 and RAM is 8 GB using AWSCLI commands

Comment: At this time, no, You still have to [get the pricing API JSON](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/) and parse it to find what you want.

Comment: I like the page http://www.ec2instances.info and they made a page for RDS instance too http://www.ec2instances.info/rds/ which compiles most of information

Answer (score 0):

nope, that's not possible, check [issue-1279](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1279) in aws-cli github. You cannot even easily get a list of the available types (you can use `aws gamelift describe-ec2-instance-limits`).